# When to use using

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I use “using” blocks in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567138/when-should-i-use-using-blocks-in-c)

A lot of classes maybe need to be wrapped by using. Is there a simple rule for the using?

Rick

Comment: Duplicate of [When should I use "using" blocks in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567138/when-should-i-use-using-blocks-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a class implements `IDisposable` then generally you should wrap its use in `using` (if you can). In my experience that's not "a lot of classes". It *should* only be classes that use unmanaged resources and classes that wrap those.

Comment: Just to explicitly  note the special cases, in some cases the using block forces you to write some not so excellent code (despite the object's implementation of IDisposable), so give it a moment's thought before opening those braces.

Answer (score 1):

If class implements `IDisposable` - you should `Dispose()` objects after you've finished working with them.

Since `using() {}` is a syntactic sugar for this task - you should wrap all `IDisposable` classes.