# Currency symbols in iOS exported CSV not showing correctly in excel

Tags: objective-c, excel, csv, encoding, symbols

I'm exporting a CSV file generated with the help of [CHCSVParser](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser), using NSUTF8StringEncoding.
Since now everything worked perfect, the fields only had text or numbers, but today I tried to add a Currency field where it shows a currency symbol written in a UITextfield.

If a upload the .csv file to Google Docs the symbols shows correctly but if I export it to Excel with the text wizard it shows **‚Ç¨** (this is for EURO symbol).

Does anyone know how to make excel show the symbol correctly?

Comment: I only know this is probably an encoding problem (from reading SO posts). I can't help you with that, but now you know at least what to search for.

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep researching in that topic

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351985/converting-unicode-to-windows-1252-for-vcards - This link should be helpful

Answer (score 2):

I had to use `NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding` to make excel understand anything.

Comment: At the end what I did was to save the value for the currency as the international symbol (i.e. EUR, GBP, etc).
Next time I'm in the same situation I'll use your approach.