# How to write to a text file in one method and then read from another method?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to Make a Stream Writer and then write some input from the Console to a file and then Read the Content out. The only problem is I want to do it in two different   methods. Write from here: `addbook()` and read from here: `list_books()`. But I can't read from that file because the stream reader does not let me access any of my variables or that file to be used again.

```
//So I am trying to write from the static void addbook method and then read from the static void list_books method

//I want to Write from one static void and then I want  to read them from a different method.

static void addbook()
{
    //Here is where I get my strings that I will write

    Console.Write("Book Title:");
    string title = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("ISBN#:");
    string isbn = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Author:");
    string author = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Publish Date:");
    string publish_date = Console.ReadLine();

    //Here Is where I create the Stream Reader and Writer
    //And where I write to the file
    var fs = File.Open("Librarybooks.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    var sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
    var sr = new StreamReader(fs);

    sw.WriteLine(title.ToCharArray());
    sw.WriteLine(isbn.ToCharArray());
    sw.WriteLine(author.ToCharArray());
    sw.WriteLine(publish_date.ToCharArray());

    Console.WriteLine("Book added Successfully!!");
}

static void list_books()
{
    //Here is where I want to read from so I can just call the list_books method.
    //But I can't access the StreamReader or StreamWriter
    //I just want to be able to read from the file.
}
```

Comment: You would have to declare your `StreamReader` within the scope of your `list_books` method in order to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private const string FILE_PATH = "Librarybooks.txt";

static void addbook()
{
    //Here is where I get my strings that I will write

    Console.Write("Book Title:");
    string title = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("ISBN#:");
    string isbn = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Author:");
    string author = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Publish Date:");
    string publish_date = Console.ReadLine();

    //Here Is where I create the Stream Reader and Writer
    //And where I write to the file
    using (var fs = File.Open(FILE_PATH, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(title.ToCharArray());
                sw.WriteLine(isbn.ToCharArray());
                sw.WriteLine(author.ToCharArray());
                sw.WriteLine(publish_date.ToCharArray());

                Console.WriteLine("Book added Successfully!!");
             }
         }
     }
}

static void list_books()
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FILE_PATH))
    {
       string fileContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: So I did that and then it gives this error:  "The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Kyson Gardner\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Library\Library\bin\Debug\Librarybooks.txt' because it is being used by another process." How can I fix this?

Comment: You did not close the filestream or rather I did not in the code. I updated the answer. Please try it.

Answer (score 2):

MSDN provides examples of how to do both things

- [How to: Write Text to a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w.aspx)
- [How to: Read Text from a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx)

As you can see from he examples, you don't need to convert strings into arrays of characters to write them.

You will also notice both example using the [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) keyword.  There's an explanation of why you want to use that construct in this question (and probably many others): [When should I use “using” blocks in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567138/when-should-i-use-using-blocks-in-c)

It looks like you already fond the [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3saad2h5.aspx) class, you could take advantage of the other methods in it that are specifically designed for working with text files.  You can decide if you want to write to/read from a file in terms of lines or entire contents.  There are examples of how to use the `File` class here:

- [How to: Write to a Text File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k)
- [How to: Read From a Text File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b)

---

Based on the code it looks like you're just starting out with programming, consider putting your code up [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  That way you can get helpful tips about how to write better code.