# Write to file with FileStream without using "using"

Tags: c#, events, file-io, filestream, using

I have a class member variable `_stream` which is a `FileStream`. This variable gets initialized in the constructor and needs to stick around until I'm done with the class. I have another class that raises an event every time something needs to be written to the file. In my main class I have an event handler that performs the actual writing. I tried the following code as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657643/writing-to-txt-file-with-streamwriter-and-filestream):

```
void MyEventHandler(string message)
{
    using (_stream)
        using (StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter(_stream))
           s.WriteLine(message);
}
```

But this doesn't work because `using` disposes of my `FileStream` before I'm done with it. What should I be doing instead?

Comment: Where does _stream come from? What is the actual error / symptom? This question is unclear and incomplete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you clearly need to remove the `using (_stream)` as that will dispose of the stream directly.

Secondly, the `StreamWriter` will *also* dispose of the stream as well, with your current code. Options for this are:

- Don't have a `using` statement for the `StreamWriter` either, but explicitly flush the writer if you need it to be written to the file immediately:

  ```
  void MyEventHandler(string message)
  {
      var s = new StreamWriter(_stream);
      s.WriteLine(message);
      s.Flush();
  }
  ```
- Use the constructor for `StreamWriter` which allows you to control whether or not the stream is closed when the `StreamWriter` is disposed:

  ```
  void MyEventHandler(string message)
  {
      using (var s = new StreamWriter(_stream, Encoding.UTF8, 1024, true))
      {
           s.WriteLine(message);
      }
  }
  ```
- Change your code so that instead of a `Stream`, the field in your class is a `TextWriter` to start with (which is initialized as a `StreamWriter` for whatever file/stream you want) - then you don't need to create a new `StreamWriter` in the method at all.

As Servy notes, your own class should implement `IDisposable` and dispose of the stream/writer in its `Dispose` method.

Answer (score 6):

Just omit the `using`.

Note that in this case the class that is defining this method should implement `IDisposable` and it should dispose of the stream in its `Dispose` method.  The user of this class should declare it in a `using` block.

Comment: Note that `StreamWriter` will try to dispose stream too if you `using (StreamWriter s...)` ... One need to be careful mixing writers and raw streams - at very least `.Flush()` writer when you are done.

Answer (score 2):

`using` is used for local variables in a function to implicitly dispose the object, but when it is a member of a class you should dispose it when the class is disposed.

```
class YourClass : IDisposable
{
    ....
    public void Dispose()
    {
       Dispose(true);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
      if (disposing)
      {
        _stream.Dispose();
      }
    }
}
```