# Error during delete operation in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is the code of my grid view delete operation using `storedprocedure`. I get this error: `{"No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label to a known managed provider native type."}`

```
protected void GVEmployee_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GVEmployee.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    Control c1 = row.FindControl("Label1");
    Label l1 = (Label)c1;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCM"].ConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from Spempdet where Id= ' " + ID , con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", l1);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Bind();
}
```

Comment: I am getting error here cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();   An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know about SQL you need to pass the value within a ' ' 
So yours SQL command should looks like

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from Spempdet where Id= ' " + ID+" ' " , con);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are passing the label as a parameter. 
I assume the label text contains the ID you want to use in your delete statement so you should change the code line:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", l1);
```

to

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", l1.Text);
```

Second, I assume you also have the wrong delete query.
You add the @Id parameter but you don't use it in your query.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from Spempdet where Id = @id", connection)
```

Thirth, don't forget your using statements. Both SqlConnection and SqlCommand are disposable.
Please check [When should I use "using" blocks in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567138/when-should-i-use-using-blocks-in-c) for more information.